# Select2 Crashes when loading large table

Tags: apache, symfony, doctrine-orm, xampp, jquery-select2

I'm currently trying to load a large table (8800 Rows / 2.5 MiB) however it crashes. In Chrome F12 I get an error of:

```
POST http://localhost/web/app_dev.php/_entity_find 500 (Internal Server Error) main.js:3
k.cors.a.crossDomain.send main.js:3
n.extend.ajax main.js:3
(anonymous function)
```

(main.js is my compiled JS containing select2)

I have other 'select2 autocomplete' fields on the same page searching smaller tables which work perfectly fine.

Looking in Apache error.log I have this error:

```
[client ::1:55760] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal
redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion'
to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.,
referer: http://localhost/web/app_dev.php/user/prod/new
```

If I load the field as a plain choice field It loads fine, rather large and takes around 7 seconds but loads all the same.

Using Symfony 2.4.* , Doctrine2 and the most up to date download of select2.

## EDIT

Right well, after deleting all but 2 rows just to test the table on something small I discovered it still failed to load. I've now rebuilt the table but with a ID Column with standard Auto Increment. Previously I was importing a large data-set which contained a Id table starting at 1001 unfortunately as far as my digging has uncovered it was this column being set as Primary which broke Select2. Don't understand how or why but at least it works now. I hope this can save someone else days of digging only to find your digging in the wrong area completely.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, loading that amount of data in debug mode (`app_dev.php`) will load much more data in memory, i.e. for simple list with 100 items it will load something like 3x memory than in production mode, it's caused by loggers, stopwatches and similar debug stuff.

Second, for such amount of data you should use [`ajax`](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#ajax) or even [`ajax infinite`](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#infinite) settings for Select2, probably with i.e. some [preloaded items](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#data_array). This way you will have more calls to your website, but it will not crash, and render normally.

Comment: Unfortunately it is already using Ajax and I receive the same error when using app.php not only app_dev.php.

Comment: Currently deleting records from the table 500 at a time to see at which point it kills it. If I get to 0 I know I've broken it else where ;-)

Comment: Got the table down to a total of 5 rows and still no luck so must have absolutely nothing to do with the data size but a messed up table/table connection. Will do some more digging now.

Answer (score 0):

Right well, after deleting all but 2 rows just to test the table on something small I discovered it still failed to load. I've now rebuilt the table but with a ID Column with standard Auto Increment. Previously I was importing a large data-set which contained a Id table starting at 1001 unfortunately as far as my digging has uncovered it was this column being set as Primary which broke Select2. Don't understand how or why but at least it works now. I hope this can save someone else days of digging only to find your digging in the wrong area completely.

If someone could explain the reason for it I will happily accept your answer.